# select all rows from table 1 and mark rows that exist in table 2

Tags: mysql

I have a table of suppliers (id, name, address)

I have another table linking suppliers with customers (accredited_suppliers-> supplier_id, customer_id)

I want to select all suppliers with an identifier showing if there is a relationship with the customer (customer_id)

i.e. results would look like:

suppliers:

```
id, name, address, customer_link
1, name1, address1, null
2, name2, address2, Yes
3, name3, address3, null
4, name4, address4, Yes
```

Some more information:

Supplier Table:
id
name
...
...

Customer Table:
id
name
...
...

AccreditedSuppliers Tables:
id
customer_id
supplier id

e.g. I want all suppliers, with a column flagging all suppliers linked to customer id=100

Comment: It is not clear what are relationships between tables (what are primary keys and foreign keys) in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*, IF(count(`t2`.`customer_id`) > 0, 'yes', NULL) as customer_link
FROM `suppliers` AS `t1`
LEFT JOIN `accredited_suppliers` AS `t2` ON `t2`.`supplier_id` = `t1`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're either looking for a list of suppliers who have a customer

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE supplier_id IN ( SELECT supplier_id FROM customers );
```

Or you are looking to have a join, depending on the way the relation ship works you'll need to figure out what type of join you want, e.g is the relationship 1-1, 1-m, n-m?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, address, customer_id as customer_link  FROM suppliers LEFT JOIN accredited_suppliers ON suppliers.id=accredited_suppliers.supplier_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this should work -

```
select id, name, address, 
(case when exists(select 'x' from linkedtable where id in (supplier_id)) 
   then 'Yes' else null end) as customer_link
from suppliers
```