# MySQL Statement not returning as expected

Tags: mysql, join, if-statement

I have 3 tables:

1. SUPPLIERS:
   id, name, address, suburb, state, phone, email, deleted
2. CUSTOMERS:
   id, name, address, suburb, state, phone, email, deleted
3. ACCREDITED_SUPPLIERS:
   id, supplier_id, customer_id

I want to display all SUPPLIERS and 'tag' those that are already linked in ACCREDITED_SUPPLIERS...

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS s.id, s.name, s.suburb, s.state, s.phone, s.email, s.deleted, 
IF( ac.customer_id =  '220', 1, 0 ) AS accredited
FROM suppliers s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN accredited_suppliers ac ON ac.supplier_id = s.id 
WHERE s.deleted='0'  
ORDER BY s.name
```

This statement only returns 10 'tagged' rows

For some reason it is missing 3 rows inexplicably!

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `accredited_suppliers` 
WHERE  `customer_id` =  '220'
```

RETURNS: 13 rows

Is my statement above correct? Am I issuing it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you just want:

```
select
  s.id AS supplier_id,
  IF(a.supplier_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS accredited
from
  SUPPLIERS s
    left join
      ACCREDITED_SUPPLIERS a
    ON
      s.id = a.supplier_id AND
      a.customer_id = 220;
```

Comment: There's my 3 missing rows!!! This fixes the problem but what was wrong with the original statement?  Is it just way off?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're doing in your old statement =) It's silly... You were probably thinking too difficult. Evaluate as simple as possible: I want all suppliers (FROM) and then optionally (LEFT JOIN) a matching accredited. Sounds like a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Don't forget the `WHERE deleted = '0'`... And there go your 3 rows: missing again?

Comment: Got first statement in here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566422/select-all-rows-from-table-1-and-mark-rows-that-exist-in-table-2